# How to get list from DataFrame where type is equal to a number in Python?

Tags: python, pandas

I would like to get all the files from the `DataFrame` `listOfAllTracks`with the same type, so I could make a `DataFrame` with the length of that list.

This is the `dataframe` `listOfAllTracks` I get:

[image: This is the dataframe listOfAllTracks I get]

And this is what I would like to become:

[image: And this is what I would like to become]

Comment: Assuming the int type codes correspond to string types, use groupby and .count() then map the right strings to the ints

Comment: Consider copying the dataframe here as code

Comment: Thanks, this works!